# `createTree: already exists (File exists)` error when running `ghcjs-boot`

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

When running `ghcjs-boot` I get a whole bunch of:

```
ignoring unexpected entry type in tar. only normal files and directories (no links) are supported:
ghcjs-boot/./@LongLink
```

Before finally:

```
ghcjs-boot: /Users/<user>/.ghcjs/x86_64-darwin-0.2.1-8.0.2/ghcjs/ghcjs-boot/boot/aeson/tests/JSONTestSuite/parsers/test_JSONKit/test-JSONKit.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/nst: createTree: already exists (File exists)
```

And then failure.

For more information my globally installed `ghc` is 8.2. Since that doesn't work for `ghcjs`, I installed `ghc-8.0` via brew and modified my `PATH` before running the command so that it pointed to `ghc-8.0`. I also am using `cabal-2.0.0.1` and am on `OS X Yosemite 10.10.5`.

Any idea what the issue is / how I can fix.

Comment: Building GHCJS yourself is not a nice task. Even if you succeed today, you have  no guarantee that you can rebuild it tomorrow, You may have new issues with the next GHC version. Therfore the [common opinion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/7mm3i8/what_is_the_best_way_to_setup_a_ghcghcjs_full/) is to use the [reflex-platform](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform) even if you don't use reflex!

Comment: @Jogger Thanks! I find it quite funny that when I open up the stackoverflow question I asked, I get a link back to the reddit post that I made.